# SQL-statement with JOIN to LINQ-statement

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, join

How would you write the following SQL as a Linq-statement?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Projekt i 
LEFT JOIN Projekt j on i.name=j.id
```

Comment: Is this pure Linq using in-memory collections, or Entity Framework?

Comment: Seems a bit of a crazy way to have a hierarchical table to me

Comment: entity framework @gunr2171

Comment: Can you give an explanation to why you need to do this join? You're joining the same table. What's your schema look like?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: You can also use online tools.
https://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have for example these two classes:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }
}
```

then with **Method Syntax**(MS) for **LEFT OUTER JOIN** we'll have this code below:

```
var JoinedTables = context.Employee.GroupJoin(Address,
                                              emp => emp.AddressId,
                                              add => add.ID,
                                              (emp, add) => new { emp, add })
                                   .SelectMany(x => x.add.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                                              (employee, address) => new { employee, address }))
                                   .ToList();
```

But with **Query Syntax**(QS)

> which is more understandable for humans

for **LEFT OUTER JOIN** again all you have to do is:

```
var JoinedTables = (from emp in Employee
                   join add in Address
                   on emp.AddressId equals add.ID
                   into EmployeeAddressGroup
                   from address in EmployeeAddressGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new { employee, address }).ToList();
```